# Regarding "Local variables should not be declared and then immediately returned or thrown"

Tags: javascript, async-await

Given the code:

```js
async getData() {

    const response = await handleRequest(…);

    return response;
}
```

Many of static code analyzers mark this  code with an [issue](https://rules.sonarsource.com/javascript/RSPEC-1488) *"Local variables should not be declared and then immediately returned or thrown"*.

Formally, yes, `const response` is not mandatory here but in my opinion, this extra variable simplifies the debugging, since I can put a breakpoint on a line with `return response;` and clearly see the returning value (not a Promise) before I return it outside.

If I follow suggestion of the code analyzer, and refactor this code to:

```js
async getData() {

    return await handleRequest(…);

}
```

I'll get a [proposal](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-return-await) to remove an extra `await`, but this, in my opinion, will decrease the code readability, since a developer must bear in mind that using `return await` inside an async function keeps the current function in the call stack until the Promise that is being awaited has resolved. While `return await handleRequest(…);` states it explicitly, which is always good for the code readability.

Are these two cases just a matter of a taste or in this case I should follow the code analyzer proposals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mostly I see it same as you do. Not every optimization must be done only because it is possible. It might become interesting if you get any performance issues, because it is a heavily used function. But normally I also prefer more clear and readable code –

Comment: Good answer, but the question is off-topic.

Comment: @pacmaninbw, does this question suit more to SO?

Comment: @Mike I suggest you look at the help sections on each of the sites, especially "How do I ask a good question?", "What types of questions should I avoid asking?" and "What topics can I ask about here?". [Stack Overflow Help](https://stackoverflow.com/help). [Code Review Help](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help). I don't think this would be a good question on SO either. Please read [Where can I get help?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-sites-do-i-post-on).